# Variables loses value inside a while loop only

Tags: java, local-variables

I am trying to compare data from 2 different spreadsheets in excel. When I am doing this I store the values from certain cells in the Check variables(`userCheck`, `sessionCheck`, and `idCheck`). What I am finding is that the between the first check and the second check they have different values which means before/during the nested while loop the Check variables have the values that they were initiated with, but after the nested while loop, they have the values defined in the if statement just before the nested while loop.

I don't understand why the value doesn't change inside the nest while loop basically.

**Java**

```
String userCheck = "x";
int sessionCheck = -1;
int idCheck = -1;
double[] predict;
predict = new double[13];

rows.next();
rows2.next();
while(rows.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rows.next();
    Cell msg = row.getCell(49);
    Cell id = row.getCell(64);
    Cell user = row.getCell(0);
    Cell session = row.getCell(1);
    if(msg != null) {

        if(msg.getStringCellValue().charAt(0)!='<'
          &&msg.getStringCellValue().charAt(1)!='k'
          &&!msg.getStringCellValue().substring(0,7).equals("Awesome")) {
            idCheck = (int)id.getNumericCellValue();
            userCheck = user.getStringCellValue();
            sessionCheck = (int)session.getNumericCellValue();
        }


        while(rows2.hasNext()) {
            Row row2 = rows2.next();
            Cell user2 = row2.getCell(0);
            Cell session2 = row2.getCell(1);
            Cell id2 = row2.getCell(2);
            //First Check
            System.out.println(userCheck);

            if(user2.getStringCellValue().equals(userCheck)) {

                if((int)session2.getNumericCellValue() == sessionCheck) {

                    if((int)id2.getNumericCellValue() == idCheck) {

                        for(int i=0;i<13;i++) {
                            predict[i] = 
 double)row2.getCell(i+2).getNumericCellValue();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        //Second Check
        System.out.println(userCheck);

//code and brackets continue on below but i figured this block should be enough
```

Comment: what value? which while loop? have you debugged your code?

Comment: @Theo - Can you please add more details on second loop? It is difficult to help you when only a part of the code is shown to us.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to post a comment, so i post it as answer:

i think your while loops are intended to do something like this (pseudocode):

```
for all row1 in rows
  for all row2 in rows2
    compare row1 with row2
```

e.g. you want to compare every row from rows with every row from rows2? (if not, don't read further. I didn't get it right then.)

however, you don't use `for each` loops, you're using iterators. And you initiate them before both of the while loop. This means, you're entering the outer `while` loop as intended, then the inner `while` loop as intended, too. Then the inner while loop iterates over all rows of rows2 (until `rows2.hasNext() == false`)  also as intended. but when the outer while loop faces the inner loop the second time, the iterator for rows2 is not reset. So `rows2.hasNext() == false` still holds and the inner loop is never entered again.

Comment: I am going to play around with this but I think this is the problem. Thanks